# how to give badges to iconbutton in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, frontend, icons

how to give a badge to an iconbutton in flutter, whenever i try wrap an iconbutton with badge.Badge widget or Badge widget it does not work!!

p.s. I referred to the documentation and used badges.Badge but it still does not work

Comment: can u share some Image Previews like, 1. what u want 2. what u r getting?

Comment: you need to define smallSize or largeSize else add a label widget to it.

Comment: you should share some code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what you are doing wrong, you should provide your code sample so that I can get a better understanding of the issue.

But still I've created a simple example and hoping it will be helpful.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: MyWidget());
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Badge(
          child: IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return const AlertDialog(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.done),
                    iconColor: Colors.white,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    content: Text('Badge with IconButton successful.'),
                    contentTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Badge Widget wrapped over IconButton*

[image: Badge wrapped over IconButton]

*IconButton onPressed working*

[image: IconButton onPressed working]

Answer (score 0):

```
  Badge(
                smallSize: 20,
                label: Text('1'),
                child: IconButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(Icons.circle_notifications))),
```

Try using it like this.
Refer: https://dartpad.dev/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1